# How can a web developer set the priority of resources in http2?

Tags: http2

For example, I want to load `jquery`, `bootstrap` and `handlebars` javascript files as soon as possible. `bootstrap` depends on `jquery` so it makes sense to have that download complete after `jquery`. How can I set `http2` priorities to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, but if it were, can you describe how you will you "awake" `bootstrap` as soon as `jquery` is loaded?

Comment: I was hoping http2's dependency tree model would enable me to specify the run order

Comment: No, that tree model is established by the browser using its own semantics. The server doesn't need to honor it however. But think about my question...

Comment: Currently we use requirejs for this purpose like so;   require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min'],
      bootstrap: '/common/components/bootstrap-3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min'
    },
    shim: {
      bootstrap: {
        deps: ["jquery"]
      }
    }
  });
  require(
    [
      'jquery',
      'bootstrap'
    ],

Comment: Aha. Well RequireJS is ideal when deploying HTTP/2 PUSH, we have used it a few times. Then our server do priorities based on the dependencies dag that RequireJS files create. The interesting thing with your question is  about prioritizing non-PUSH fetches in the same way. I'm just writing about priorities [here](https://beta.shimmercat.com/info/articles/learning-and-pushing/), (I uploaded partial version just for this comment). But you are bringing a very interesting point...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the priorities for the transfers the browsers do, and in fact the browser should know better than the server. Like if the user scrolls away the view port or change active tab etc the server can't know but the client can chance and set prio based on such things.

Server-side you can use server push to offer resources to the client before the client has had a chance to ask for them, but that also needs to be done with caution since if the client is likely to already have it (cached) a push is a bandwidth waste (although limited to at most the initial window size for new streams).

Comment: I agree that the browser will know better about things like user scrolling. I was looking for a way in the initial html file to specify different priorities for scripts. I want my scripts to load asynchronously so as not to block rendering. Some scripts like analytics and chat are less important than others. Can I set their priorites lower in the html?

Comment: There's no standard way to do that right now to my knowledge. Maybe something will be created over time.

Answer (score 0):

"I want my scripts to load asynchronously so as not to block rendering. Some scripts like analytics and chat are less important than others. Can I set their priorities lower in the html? "

Yes, you can put the script tags to the bottom of the body to prevent render blocking